# Remove index file in Coordinator

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to remove `index.php` from url in Coordinator for that I want to change in `httpd.conf` file what is file path of that file in linux.

I am already done this changes in .htaccess file but still can not remove `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It would depend on the linux distro you are using, but there is no reason you shouldn't be able to do this from the .htaccess file either.

Comment: @gabe3886 i can not remove index.php do you know what is file path for httpd.conf

Comment: also make sure `$config['index_page'] = '';` is set.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the httpd.conf will vary from distribution to distribution.  The usual locations are:

/etc/httpd or
/etc/apache2

However, you should be able to do what you want just through the .htaccess file.  I found [this article](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-administration/1338-get-rid-of-indexphp-in-your-joomla-urls) and, whilst it is specifically for Joomla, there is no reason it shouldn't work for non-joomla sites.  Basically, your .htaccess needs to be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With this my problem is sloved

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```